# Using Source Generators in a NuGet library targeting consumer code

Tags: c#, code-generation, c#-8.0

I am trying to move a lot of my runtime reflection stuff to AOT with the new Source Generators, however I am facing a few issues.
Let me first talk through the requirements I have.

- The code of the library needs to target .NET 5, but not for the Source Generator itself, although it would be a nice to have, but according to the [MS dev-blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introducing-c-source-generators/#can-i-change-the-tfm-in-a-source-generator) it is not yet possible.
- The source generator itself shouldn't be required to install separately from the original NuGet package.

Now to a more visual example, imagine package A to be the NuGet library which should contain code for the user of the package A. Package B, the package containing the source generators which again should be executed on the users code-base and not on package A. Package B should be shipped with package A.

Why it is such a big deal to ship the Source Generator with the library? The SG's will produce code which is required for library itself.

I might have skipped something while reading through the docs, however I am just unable to figure it out, assuming this is even possible.

Comment: "Why it is such a big deal to ship the Source Generator with the library?" - because (using `npm` terminology) it's a "dev-dependency" (i.e. something you need to *build* a project), not a runtime dependency. It's generally a good idea to keep them separate otherwise you end up having too many moving-parts on the end-user's machine, for example.

Comment: FWIW, NuGet is working on adding first-class support for dev-dependencies, until then there are workarounds and alternative approaches: https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/DevelopmentDependency-support-for-PackageReference

Comment: @Dai In my case I am working on an ORM and it would be a very painful experience to install another package by hand just to have the core module working. However it seems like that, if I set the `developmentDependency  = true` it will include the analyzers from the library itself right? Because IIRC that is already a thing and some package do install with `IncludeAssets` tag.

Comment: @Twenty Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @Timo I actually did, I forgot about this question, look at the answer I posted. Thanks for reminding me though!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually turned out to be easier than expected. It is possible to ship the Source Generator in the same NuGet package by referencing it as an Analyzer with the `PackagePath` argument in the .csproj file of the parent project.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="Path\To\SourceGenerator\bin\$(Configuration)\netstandard2.0\NameOfSourceGenerator.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="analyzers/dotnet/cs" Visible="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have come to the same [conclusion](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/55229#issuecomment-933233861).